# How to configure strongly-typed entity Ids (value objects) with OData EDM

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, blazor

I am new to OData and EDM. I'm trying to implement them in a solution in Visual Studio 2019 having a Blazor WebAssembly project and a .NET Core 3.1 web API. The problem I'm experiencing is in the web API project.

To configure OData with EDM I'm calling:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
//etc.
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
//etc.
                endpoints.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(1000);
                endpoints.MapODataRoute("api", "api", GetEdmModel());
// etc.
            });
        }
}
```

The GetEdmModel() function is:

```
private IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            odataBuilder.EntitySet<ViewStudentDto>("Students");

            return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
        }
```

At runtime I get the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity set Students is based on type > MySchool.Dtos.Students.ViewStudentDto that has no keys defined

I understand the error. It's complaining that my DTO class ViewStudentDto hasn't defined a unique identifier property. But it has. And it's public and the property is named `Id` according to convention. The problem is that the type of the property is not one of the Edm primitive types from OData spec:

- Edm.Boolean
- Edm.Byte
- Edm.Date
- Edm.DateTimeOffset
- Edm.Decimal
- Edm.Duration
- Edm.Guid
- Edm.Int16
- Edm.Int32
- Edm.Int64
- Edm.SByte
- Edm.String
- Edm.TimeOfDay

My Id property is a strongly-typed Id (a value object) called `StudentId` whose underlying type is `System.Guid`, which maps to `Edm.Guid`.

It's possible to use strongly typed Ids with Entity Framework Core and Json Serialization by using TypeConverters, JsonConverters and EF configuration. Surely it must be possible to use strongly typed Ids with EDM/OData using some kind of type conversion?

Can anybody please guide me how configure EDM/OData to recognize that my `StudentId` value object can be unpacked to a simple `Edm.Guid` so that it doesn't throw this exception?

If the above is not enough to see the problem I'm having, there is a minimal repro of it available here:

https://github.com/BenjaminCharlton/ODataWithStronglyTypedIdsRepro

Thanks for your advice!

Benjamin

Comment: Can you post your `ViewStudentDto` and `StudentId` classes ?

Comment: Thanks for your continued support! I didn't provide that in the original post because I didn't want to dump a load of unnecessary code on you. But yes, sure! If it will help you to help me I'll happily share it. I have made this Git repository with the minimal amount of code required to show the problem. It's at: https://github.com/BenjaminCharlton/ODataWithStronglyTypedIdsRepro

Answer (score 0):

Use the builder to specify the key :

```cs
private IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    var entitySet = odataBuilder.EntitySet<ViewStudentDto>("Students");

    entitySet.EntityType.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    entitySet.EntityType.Ignore(e => e.StudentId);

    return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

And add update the DTO to use the Id property:

```cs
public class ViewStudentDto
{
    public Guid Id { get => StudentId.Value; set => StudentId = new StudentId(value); }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public StudentId StudentId { get; set; }

    public DateTime WhenEnrolled { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this doesn't help Edm to convert my `StudentId` object into a `Guid`. Your idea inspired me to try something very similar though. I tried this: `entitySet.EntityType.HasKey<Guid>(s => s.Id.Value);` where `s` is the ViewStudentDto, `s.Id` is the strongly typed StudentId object and s.Id.Value is the `System.Guid` property underlying the StudentId. It compiles but it doesn't run. It fails with a `System.InvalidOperationException` "MemberExpressions must be bound to the LambdaExpression parameter."

Comment: can the method in "https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/how-to-consume-sql-spatial-data-with-web-api-v2-2-for-odata-v4/" help you?

Comment: @benjamin I updated the answer I make a PR to your repo with a working code

Comment: I'm grateful to both of you, @SamXu and @agua-from-mars for this input! I'm certainly learning a lot about oData configuration by working through this problem! So @agua-from-mars, I accepted your pull request and studied it with interest. Without a doubt, it builds and runs now, thank you, but it's configured to ignore the strongly typed Id (which was there by design) and use an additional primitively typed `Id`. Do we have to add another property to the model because oData cannot be configured to use the strongly typed one?

Comment: Thank you too, @SamXu for the link to your article. I learned a lot from reading it. It isn't jumping out at me how this configures oData to use a strongly typed Id as its key though. In EntityFramework, in your instance of `IEntityTypeConfiguration`, you would call `builder.Property(s => s.Id).HasConversion(id => id.Value, v => new StudentId(v));` to configure EF to convert between the primitive type and the strongly typed Id. So I was looking for a similarly named method or extension method on oData's NavigationSourceConfiguration object, but didn't find one. Do you know of one, please?

Comment: @benjamin It's not really because of OData but because on your client side you cannot deserialize well this StudentId which doesn't have setter for Value, So it gonna have a new value each time you deserialize it. And I guess it's not expected. I get you're using DDD, but your DTO should be read/writte

Comment: The StudentId class can be deserialized from JSON using the StudentIdJsonConverter that was applied using the JsonConverterAttribute. You cannot set the Value property of the StudentId class by design because the StudentId is supposed to be an immutable class like a string, or a Guid, or an int. However, that doesn't mean it must get a new value every time you deserialize it. You can pass a particular Guid in the constructor each time an instance if the class is constructed. I shall update the code in the repository to show that because it I realize that aspect wasn't realistic in my repro :-)

Comment: Ok, so Ignore the Id in Json serialization instead and use the StudentId should work

Answer (score 0):

I have also been fighting with strongly typed ids and OData and have found that on occasion creating a property interface to the object can help in situations like this.

In my case I make a new property called `IdInterface`

```
[StronglyTypedId]
[EfCoreValueConverterAttribute(typeof(EfCoreValueConverter))]
public partial struct CompanyId { }

public class Company
{
    public CompanyId Id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int IdInterface
    {
        get => Id.Value;
        set { Id = new CompanyId(value); }
    }
}
```

And then change the EDM to reference `IdInterface` as the key, remove `Id`, and renamed `IdInterface` to be `Id`

```
var a = builder.EntitySet<Company>(nameof(CompaniesController).Replace("Controller", ""));
        a.EntityType.HasKey(x => x.IdInterface);
        a.EntityType.Ignore(x => x.Id);
        a.EntityType.Property(x => x.IdInterface).Name = "Id";
```